# Inline functions in debug build (Visual C++ 2008)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline

The game engine I am working with is too slow in the debug build and is impossible to debug the game. One of the things I would like is for the compiler to inline small functions (especially in Vector/Matrix and container classes). This may or may not speed up the game in debug build. Before profiling heavily and trying to figure out bottlenecks I thought I would try this first as I would have to do minimal work and the results may be promising.

So, is there a way to get the Visual C++ compiler to inline functions in debug builds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Project options -> C/C++ -> Optimization -> Inline Function Expansion. Turn this to `/Ob2`. Also make sure that Debug Information Format (under C/C++ -> General) isn't set to `/ZI` (set it to `/Zi` instead if it is). Do this in your Debug configuration.

In Release, inline function expansion is implied by other optimization settings, so even though by default all configurations say "Default" for the setting, the behavior is indeed different.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez.aspx

(original poster)
I believe Debug builds should have inline expansion behavior the same as release; there's really no reason not to.

(editor)
The main reason to not do this is that functions that do get inlined won't show up at all when stepping through code in the debugger, resulting in "invisible" code.

Comment: I checked this as correct as there is no indication in VS help files that this will not work for debug builds (no compiler warnings of unsupported compiler flag either). I am able to break into the simplest one line functions however which I am not able to do so in release. Not sure whether it is inlining unless I look at assembly.

Comment: Will this cause the debugger to get "confused" ?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing two compiler options. `/O` influences optimization, including inlining. `/ZI` creates the PDB file for debugging. They can be set independently.

It may be useful to clone the "Debug" configuration, though, and create a "Debug-optimized" configuration with both `/O1` and `/ZI`.

Comment: They can be, yes, but with optimizations on, too many things are optimized. For example, strings cannot be debugged properly most of the time with optimizations on and with debug info. The debugger fails to show values for many local variables with optimizations on even if there is debug info.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [`__forceinline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8y1yy88%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).  Be sure to read about debug builds on that page (turn off the `/Ob0` option).

My suspicion is that this will not change the performance very much.  Another thing to try if you haven't already is just to add symbols to a release build.  It works fairly well for debugging a lot of issues.

Answer (score -3):

`DEBUG` is defined by Visual Studio when a project is compiled in Debug mode so:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  inline void fn() {
#else
  void fn() {
#endif
```

Comment: Problem is, `inline` keyword is completely ignored by the compiler when in debug